# Metadata for Read-only from layout!

Tags: lightning

I was wondering how do i get if a particular field is set to read-only on the layout using Metadata APIs? The reason is, i am designing a lightning component and i wanted to still adhere to those read-only rules specified in the layout.

Any ideas?

Comment: I do not know, but I think that the new [User Interface API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started.htm) should handle that

Comment: @ItaiShmida Thanks for your reply. Let me give it a try.